# perspective projection with aspect ratio != 1.0 for cubemap-like creation of overall image

Tags: opengl

I render 3 images (left-view, center-view, right-view) with 90° horizontal foV and map them on 3 grids that create an overall image (basically like left, front and right views of a cubemap texture). Therefore the 3 unique images have to fit together somehow.

Everything works fine if i define the projection matrix for each image like this:

```
gluPerspective(90, 1, 0.1, 500)
```

However, since i'm trying to create an image with 210° (horizontal) and 60° (vertical) field of View, i would like to define it like this:

```
gluPerspective(60, 1.5, 0.1, 500)
```

But using this, the 3 images don't fit together in terms of their image content, foV, frustum or whatever.

So my question is: Do i have to use an aspect ratio of 1 if i want the images to fit together. And if i have to, why?

Some additional information:

i render the images in an fbo with a resolution that has the same aspect ratio like my hor./ver. foV

viewport is defined like this: glViewport (0, 0, width, height);

The modelview definition for the 3 views:

1. left-view: `gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`
2. center-view: `gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`
3. right-view: `gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`

Comment: I hope I find the time to write an exhaustive answer to that. The gist is, that FoV and aspect determine the angle of the clip planes and to get a seamless picture you have to rotate the camera by exactly that angle. `gluLookAt` and `gluPerspective` are actually rather poor methods for doing what you want. You'd be better served by working with the *frustum* directly in terms of l,r,b,t and evaluating a matching set of view rotation matrices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For some reason, it works when i use glFrustum instead of gluPerspective, but i have no idea why. So i would really appreciate an explanation for that. I thought it doesn't matter if you use glFrustum or gluPerspective as long as you are only interested in symmetric frustums?

Comment: @Dennis: They produce the same matrices. But it's easier to understand and use it for your uses if you're using a `glFrustum`-based matrix. Rather than having to try to compute directions and angles, you can just use the planes of projection directly.

Answer (score 0):

This was a sufficient explanation for me:

http://ledin.cs.sonoma.edu/CS375_OpenGL_Slides/Perspective_gluFrustum.pdf